# Tomcat/Spring SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, tomcat, springframework

I'm trying to configure my Spring application to use an SSL certificate I purchased from a CA.  I followed the directions for the [Tomcat 6.0 configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) and have imported the key into my Tomcat keystore and uncommented the SSL connector in the server.xml.  When I start Tomcat, I see the connector start on port 8443 in the Tomcat logs, but when I go to https ://example.com:8443 or http: //example.com:8443 or  https: //example.com (without the spaces - I don't have the reputation to post links), it times out.  What other configuration do I need to do to enable SSL for my Spring application.  Do I have to change the application configuration?

I'd also like to only have some URLs over SSL (login, edit profile, etc.).  How can I allow this in the Spring configuration?  If I have to have all URLs accessible over SSL, that would be ok, but not desirable.  I haven't found any tutorials that are Spring specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that need to be in the Tomcat keystore:
1. The private key and the public key pair that was generated (usually generated by the keytool -genkeypair command).
2. The certificate signing the public key (imported from the CA's reply using the keytool -importcert command).

Assuming that the above two are correct, you might want to figure out more details on why the connection is timing out. Is the SSL/TLS-enabled port accessible at example.com:8443 or is it listening on a different network interface? Moreover, are all the attributes specified for the Connector correct (the Tomcat logs would provide a hint or two)? Finally, you might want to use the [javax.net.debug flag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) when starting the JVM to determine if there are any other reasons for the connection timeout.

Comment: The problem was my firewall rules - I updated it to allow port 8443 and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you do the URI-specific SSL configuration using standard security constraints in your web.xml file?

Comment: Does not appear so based on my perusing of web.xml.